# Lambda Expressions and Extension methods

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, extension-methods, dynamic-linq

So I have an extension method defined like so

```
  public static String FormatString(this String source, String formatString, Object[] parameters)
  {
               return String.Format(formatString, parameters);
  }
```

and from investigation, I have come to learn that when the above method is invoked, it expects 3 parameters and not two even though in code I would invoke it on a String instance like so

```
String StringInstance = "MYSTRINGINSTANCE";
String StringFormatExpression = "it.FormatString(\"ui{0:D6}\", @0 )";
**  var ,args = new[] {"1", "Another", "YetAnother"}; <-- an array **
//StringInstance.FormatString(StringFormatExpression ,args );
```

Trying to create a lambda representation of this, I have the following

---

```
return Expression.Call(type, 
                       method.Name, 
                       args.Select(x=>x.GetType()).ToArray<Type>(),
                       args);
```

When I do invoke this, I get the following error message.

**No method 'FormatString' exists on type 'System.String'.**

and below is the method signature.

**-{System.String FormatString(System.String, System.String, System.Object[])}  System.Reflection.MethodBase {System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo}**

Somehow it still cannot find my Extension method to call.

When I do specify the static class in which the extension method is defined, and pass that as the first argument to the Expression.Call call, like so,

**UPDATE**

**A.**

As Requested, here is more of the code for you to see.

So I created extension methods which simplify File-related processing for me, like so.

public static IEnumerable ForEach(this IEnumerable source, string expression, params object[] values)
    {
         if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
         if (expression == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("selector");
         var enumerableList = source.AsEnumerable();

```
     IEnumerable<T> finalList = from T item in source
                     select (T) DynamicLambdaExpression.ParseLambda(item.GetType(), typeof(T), expression, values).Compile().DynamicInvoke(item);

     return finalList;
}
```

public static IEnumerable ForEachFileName(this IEnumerable sourceFilePaths, string expression,  object[] values)
      {
           if (sourceFilePaths == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
           IDictionary source = sourceFilePaths.Select((value, index) =>
           { value = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(value); return new { index, value }; }
        ).ToDictionary(x => x.index, v => v.value);
           if (expression == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("selector");

```
       IEnumerable<String> finalList = from int index in source.Keys
                                       select (String)DynamicLambdaExpression.ParseLambda(source[index].GetType(), typeof(String), expression, values).Compile().DynamicInvoke(source[index]);

       return finalList;
  }
```

B.

Then in my test, I have the following

```
String StringFormatExpression = "it.FormatString(\"ui{0:D6}\", @0 )";
var param = new[] {"1", "Another", "YetAnother"};

String result = new[] { "MyStringValue", "MySecondStringValue", "MyThirdString"}.ForEachFileName(StringFormatExpression, param).FirstOrDefault();

 Console.WriteLine(result);
```

C. As the DynamicQuery library was not able to find the extension methods I had defined earlier for my strings, I modified the code to capture extension methods as well.

```
        internal partial class ExpressionParser
 {
      Expression ParseMemberAccess(Type type, Expression instance)
      {
           if (instance != null) type = instance.Type;
           int errorPos = token.pos;
           string id = GetIdentifier();
           NextToken();
           if (token.id == TokenId.OpenParen)
           {
                if (instance != null && type != typeof(string))
                {
                     Type enumerableType = FindGenericType(typeof(IEnumerable<>), type);
                     if (enumerableType != null)
                     {
                          Type elementType = enumerableType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
                          return ParseAggregate(instance, elementType, id, errorPos);
                     }
                }
                Expression[] args = ParseArgumentList();
                MethodBase mb;

                switch (FindMethod(type, id, instance == null,instance, args,  out mb))
                {
                     case 0:
                          throw ParseError(errorPos, Res.NoApplicableMethod,
                              id, GetTypeName(type));
                     case 1:
                          MethodInfo method = (MethodInfo)mb;
                          if ((method.DeclaringType.IsAbstract && method.DeclaringType.IsSealed))
                          {
                               if (method.ReturnType == typeof(void))
                                    throw ParseError(errorPos, Res.MethodIsVoid,
                                        id, GetTypeName(method.DeclaringType));

                               Type t = mb.ReflectedType;
                               var combined = instance.Concatenate(args);
                               return Expression.Call(method, combined);
                          }

                          else if (IsPredefinedType(method.DeclaringType))
                          {
                               if (method.ReturnType == typeof(void))
                                    throw ParseError(errorPos, Res.MethodIsVoid,
                                        id, GetTypeName(method.DeclaringType));
                               return Expression.Call(instance, (MethodInfo)method, args);
                          }
                          else
                          {

                               throw ParseError(errorPos, Res.MethodsAreInaccessible, GetTypeName(method.DeclaringType));

                          }
                     default:
                          throw ParseError(errorPos, Res.AmbiguousMethodInvocation,
                              id, GetTypeName(type));
                }//end of switch method here 
           }
           else
           {
                MemberInfo member = FindPropertyOrField(type, id, instance == null);
                if (member == null)
                     throw ParseError(errorPos, Res.UnknownPropertyOrField,
                         id, GetTypeName(type));
                return member is PropertyInfo ?
                    Expression.Property(instance, (PropertyInfo)member) :
                    Expression.Field(instance, (FieldInfo)member);
           }
      }


      /// <summary>
      /// Comment Added 9/13/2013
      /// An Extension method would require that the instance be the first argument in it's parameter list
      /// </summary>
      /// <param name="type"></param>
      /// <param name="methodName"></param>
      /// <param name="staticAccess"></param>
      /// <param name="args"></param>
      /// <param name="method"></param>
      /// <returns></returns>
      int FindMethod(Type type, string methodName, bool staticAccess, Expression instance, Expression[] args, out MethodBase method)
      {
           if (type.IsGenericParameter)
           {
                BindingFlags flags = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly |
                    (staticAccess ? BindingFlags.Static : BindingFlags.Instance);

                foreach (Type t in SelfAndBaseTypes(type))
                {
                     MemberInfo[] members = t.FindMembers(MemberTypes.Method,
                         flags, Type.FilterNameIgnoreCase, methodName);
                     int count = FindBestMethod(members.Cast<MethodBase>(), instance, args, out method);
                     if (count != 0) return count;
                }
           }
           else
           {
                IEnumerable<Type> selfAndBaseTypes = SelfAndBaseTypes(type);

                foreach (Type t in selfAndBaseTypes)
                {
                     List<MethodInfo> methodinfos = new List<MethodInfo>();
                     methodinfos.AddRange(t.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly));
                     //also add extension methods
                     methodinfos.AddRange(t.GetExtensionMethods());
                     int count = FindBestMethod(methodinfos.Cast<MethodBase>(), instance, args, out method);
                     if (count != 0) return count;
                }


           }
           method = null;
           return 0;
      }

      /// <summary>
      /// Comment Added 9/13/2013
      /// An Extension method would require that the instance be the first argument in it's parameter list
      /// </summary>
      /// <param name="type"></param>
      /// <param name="methodName"></param>
      /// <param name="staticAccess"></param>
      /// <param name="args"></param>
      /// <param name="method"></param>
      /// <returns></returns>
      int FindMethod(Type type, string methodName, bool staticAccess, Expression[] args, out MethodBase method)
      {
           if (type.IsGenericParameter)
           {
                BindingFlags flags = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly |
                    (staticAccess ? BindingFlags.Static : BindingFlags.Instance);

                foreach (Type t in SelfAndBaseTypes(type))
                {
                     MemberInfo[] members = t.FindMembers(MemberTypes.Method,
                         flags, Type.FilterNameIgnoreCase, methodName);
                     int count = FindBestMethod(members.Cast<MethodBase>(), args, out method);
                     if (count != 0) return count;
                }
           }
           else
           {
                IEnumerable<Type> selfAndBaseTypes = SelfAndBaseTypes(type);

                foreach (Type t in selfAndBaseTypes)
                {
                     List<MethodInfo> methodinfos = new List<MethodInfo>();
                     methodinfos.AddRange(t.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly));
                     //also add extension methods
                     methodinfos.AddRange(t.GetExtensionMethods());
                     int count = FindBestMethod(methodinfos.Cast<MethodBase>(), args, out method);
                     if (count != 0) return count;
                }


           }
           method = null;
           return 0;
      }

      int FindBestMethod(IEnumerable<MethodBase> methods, Expression[] args, out MethodBase method)
      {
           //search for the best base method 
           int length = FindBestInstanceMethod(methods, args, out method);

           return length;
      }

      int FindBestMethod(IEnumerable<MethodBase> methods, Expression instance, Expression[] args, out MethodBase method)
      {
            //search for the best base method 
               int length = FindBestInstanceMethod(methods, args, out method);
               //in the case that no best method is found that way, try a search for Extension methods
               if(length == 0)
                    length = FindBestExtensionMethod(methods, instance, args, out method);
               return length;
      }

      private int FindBestExtensionMethod(IEnumerable<MethodBase> methods, Expression instance, Expression[] args, out MethodBase method)
      {
           MethodData[] applicable = methods.
                 Select(m => new MethodData { MethodBase = m, Parameters = m.GetParameters() }).
                 Where(m => m.MethodBase.IsDefined(typeof(ExtensionAttribute), false) 
                      && IsApplicableExtensionMethod(m, instance, args)).
                 ToArray();
           if (applicable.Length > 1)
           {
                applicable = applicable.
                    Where(m => applicable.All(n => m == n || IsBetterThan(args, m, n))).
                    ToArray();
           }
           if (applicable.Length == 1)
           {
                MethodData md = applicable[0];

                for (int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++) args[i] = md.Args[i];
                method = md.MethodBase;
           }
           else
           {
                method = null;
           }
           return applicable.Length;
      }

      private int FindBestInstanceMethod(IEnumerable<MethodBase> methods, Expression[] args, out MethodBase method)
      {
           MethodData[] applicable = methods.
              Select(m => new MethodData { MethodBase = m, Parameters = m.GetParameters() }).
              Where(m => IsApplicable(m, args)).
              ToArray();

           if (applicable.Length > 1)
           {
                applicable = applicable.
                    Where(m => applicable.All(n => m == n || IsBetterThan(args, m, n))).
                    ToArray();
           }
           if (applicable.Length == 1)
           {
                MethodData md = applicable[0];
                for (int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++) args[i] = md.Args[i];
                method = md.MethodBase;
           }
           else
           {
                method = null;
           }
           return applicable.Length;
      }


      bool IsApplicableExtensionMethod(MethodData method, Expression instance, Expression[] args)
      {
           if ((method.Parameters.Length - 1) != (args.Length)) return false;

           var argsource = instance.Concatenate(args);
           Expression[] promotedArgs = new Expression[argsource.Length];
           for (int i = 0; i < (argsource.Length); i++)
           {   
                ParameterInfo pi = method.Parameters[i];
                if (pi.IsOut) return false;
                Expression promoted = PromoteExpression(argsource[i], pi.ParameterType, false);
                if (promoted == null) return false;
                promotedArgs[i] = argsource[i];
           }
           method.Args = promotedArgs;
           return true;
      }


      bool IsApplicable(MethodData method, Expression[] args)
      {
           if (method.Parameters.Length != args.Length) return false;
           Expression[] promotedArgs = new Expression[args.Length];
           for (int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++)
           {
                ParameterInfo pi = method.Parameters[i];
                if (pi.IsOut) return false;
                Expression promoted = PromoteExpression(args[i], pi.ParameterType, false);
                if (promoted == null) return false;
                promotedArgs[i] = promoted;
           }
           method.Args = promotedArgs;
           return true;
      }

      Expression PromoteExpression(Expression expr, Type type, bool exact)
      {
           if (expr.Type == type) return expr;
           if (expr is ConstantExpression)
           {
                ConstantExpression ce = (ConstantExpression)expr;
                if (ce == nullLiteral)
                {
                     if (!type.IsValueType || IsNullableType(type))
                          return Expression.Constant(null, type);
                }
                else
                {
                     string text;
                     if (literals.TryGetValue(ce, out text))
                     {
                          Type target = GetNonNullableType(type);
                          Object value = null;
                          switch (Type.GetTypeCode(ce.Type))
                          {
                               case TypeCode.Int32:
                               case TypeCode.UInt32:
                               case TypeCode.Int64:
                               case TypeCode.UInt64:
                                    value = ParseNumber(text, target);
                                    break;
                               case TypeCode.Double:
                                    if (target == typeof(decimal)) value = ParseNumber(text, target);
                                    break;
                               case TypeCode.String:
                                    value = ParseEnum(text, target);
                                    break;
                          }
                          if (value != null)
                               return Expression.Constant(value, type);
                     }
                }
           }
           if (IsCompatibleWith(expr.Type, type))
           {
                if (type.IsValueType || exact) return Expression.Convert(expr, type);
                return expr;
           }
           return null;
      }

 }
```

D. When I run the above, I get the following Error message

**No method 'FormatString' exists on type 'System.String'.**

Comment: Give then error you edited it, it seems fairly clear.  You're not supplying the right arguments.  As you haven't shown us what arguments you're using, we can't really tell you what's wrong with them.  As the error message says, you also shouldn't be supplying a type argument for a non-generic method.  This method isn't generic.

Comment: Please see above post for the information you are looking for. I have there the details of what I am working with and the actual parameters being passed to the Extension method call.

Answer (score 1):

Extension methods don't add a method to the type's definition.  They are merely syntactic sugar for a static method call.  The `Type` that you are passing in for the containing type of `FormatStrign` is for `string`, but it *should* be for whatever type `FormatString` is defined in.  If you defined it in a class called `StringExtensions` then *that* is the `Type` you need to pass in.

Comment: I updated the information above to indicate the problem I have had with doing just what you suggest above , in my call. Any idea what I may still be doing wrong?

Comment: @Kobojunkie Yes.  Just read the error message.  It tells you what you have wrong.

Comment: Help me out here. So I am looking at the definition for the method and I still don't seem to understand what I should pass or not pass given the error messages I keep getting here. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb351107(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: @Kobojunkie Just use the second overload.  Pass in `(method, args)` and be done with it.  If your arguments don't match the signature, then you need to fix `args` to match the signature.

Comment: I am trying to match the signature there but so far not getting it. That is why I am asking for help with this. Above, I have posted not just the extension method itself, it's signature, the data I am using in this. I just need to understand what I could have wrong in my call there please.

Comment: @Kobojunkie The method requires three arguments.  You're passing in two.  They don't match.  That's what the error is telling you.  If you passed in three arguments, as the method signature requires, then it will work.

Comment: Passing in 3 arguments for a second parameter results in the error Expression of type 'System.String' cannot be used for parameter of type 'System.Object[]' of method 'System.String FormatString(System.String, System.String, System.Object[])'

Comment: @Kobojunkie And what does that tell you.  If you're just going to copy-paste your answers here without even reading them or thinking about what they mean then I'm not going to continue helping you.  What would happen if you passed a `string` to a method accepting an` object[]` as a parameter without using expressions?

Comment: I am not copy pasting WITHOUT READING. If you would simply look up there to see what I am actually doing there. I am passing there the variable args which is an array. So I am not certain what what point it changes from being an array, to simply a string here.

Comment: @Kobojunkie What is the type of the third parameter of your method.  What is the value of the third parameter of your argument array?  Do they match.  No, they don't.  Now you aren't showing (enough of) the code that you're actually using, so I couldn't tell you what it actually is even if I wanted to, but the error message very clearly states that it's not what it should be.

Comment: Ok. Sorry about that. Let me show a bit more of what I have done.

Comment: @Kobojunkie Great.  Now answer the question that I asked you in my previous comment.  Your code is as I would have guessed, and as I have explained to you, just as the error message you are getting is explaining to you in different words.  You've included tons and tons of code that isn't needed as well.  There was only one line of code that you needed to add (or more precisely, change).  The rest of what you added was just noise.